# Make One NAV link active across multiple sections (using classes???)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, nav

I need to have only one nav link in active state when a user goes through multiple sections of my website. How do I make the proper edits to this JS to make that happen?

For instance, if the default nav link id = #dinos_

I want all my sections that use section ids like #dinos_trex, #dinos_raptor, #dinos_triceratops to keep making the nav id that = #dinos_ to stay in the active state in the nav.

After further research, would someone be able to code something with 'classes'?
Lets say a set of divs share a certain class name, in this case "dinos_" how can I set an active state for just one nav item if the user is on 'any' of the related "dinos_" sections????

here is the current jquery Im using:

```
var sections = $('section'), nav = $('nav'), nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');

      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Im guessing this snippet of code in particular is where I need someone to help me redefine?

```
nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
```

Here is my HTML

```
<header id="header">

            <!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#DINOS_">DINOS</a></li> /*multiple unique section ids that contain the word dinos_ in their id name should set this to 'active */
                        <li><a href="#ROBOTS_">ROBOTS</a></li> /*multiple unique section ids that contain the word robots_ in their id name should set this to 'active */
                        <li><a href="#UNDEAD_">UNDEAD</a></li> /*multiple unique section ids that contain the word undead_ in their id name should set this to 'active */
                </ul>
                </nav>

        </header>
    <section id="dinos_" class="main style2 right dark fullscreen">
                <div class="content box style2">
                    <header>
                        <h2>DINOSAURS INTRO</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>
                     Intro to the dinos</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#main" class="button style2 up anchored" title="DINOS - INTRO">up</a>
                <a href="#dinos_trex" class="button style2 down anchored" title="DINOS - TREX">down</a>
            </section>

<section id="dinos_trex" class="main style2 left dark fullscreen">
                <div class="content box style2">
                    <header>
                        <h2>T-REX</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>
                   Section for the T-rex</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#dinos_" class="button style2 up anchored" title="DINOS - INTRO">up</a>
                <a href="#dinos_raptor" class="button style2 down anchored" title="DINOS - RAPTOR">down</a>
            </section>
<section id="dinos_raptor" class="main style2 left dark fullscreen">
                <div class="content box style2">
                    <header>
                        <h2>THE RAPTOR</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>
                   Section for the raptor/p>
                </div>
                <a href="#dinos_trex" class="button style2 up anchored" title="DINOS - TREX">up</a>
                <a href="#robots_" class="button style2 down anchored" title="ONLY ROBOTS">down</a>
            </section>
<section id="robots_" class="main style2 left dark fullscreen">
                <div class="content box style2">
                    <header>
                        <h2>ROBOTS INTRO</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>
                   Section for the Robots Intro</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#dinos_raptor" class="button style2 up anchored" title="DINOS - TREX">up</a>
                <a href="#robots_gunner" class="button style2 down anchored" title="ROBOT - GUNNER">down</a>
            </section>
<section id="robots_gunner" class="main style2 left dark fullscreen">
                <div class="content box style2">
                    <header>
                        <h2>THE ROBOT GUNNER</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>
                   Section for the gunner</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#robots_" class="button style2 up anchored" title="ROBOTS - INTRO">up</a>
                <a href="#robots_jumper" class="button style2 down anchored" title="ROBOTS - JUMPER">down</a>
            </section>
```

Comment: Have you ever used waypoints.js? I think it would make your task much easier.

Comment: @ChrisJ I don't think it make sense to use a complete library for small snippet of code.

Comment: Waypoints isn't a library. It's a plugin and it's built specifically for trigger events when elements are scrolled to.

Comment: JQuery would be the only library required which is already being used in the first example. But if you didn't use jQuery waypoints can be used without it as a dependency.

Comment: I want to say, I wont be using Waypoints on this go, because I already have scrolly and scrollgress as part of my setup,

Comment: @twinpeaks, you cannot do this with your question - removing its text after answers are there. This makes the whole chain non-understandable to the readers. Either return your question back or remove the whole post.

Answer (score 0):

Using the waypoints plugin:
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

**UPDATED**

JS:

```
   $('section').waypoint({
        handler: function (direction) {
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $("nav a[href=\"#" +this.element.id + "\"").addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

HTML with some minor changes:

```
<header id="header">
        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#dinosaurs">DINOS</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#dinosaurs_trex">ROBOTS</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#dinosaurs_raptor">UNDEAD</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="dinosaurs" class="main style2 right dark fullscreen">
        <div class="content box style2">
            <header>
                 <h2>DINOSAURS INTRO</h2>

            </header>
            <p>Intro to the dinos</p>
        </div> <a href="#main" class="button style2 up anchored" title="PAGE 1">up</a>
     <a href="#dinosaurs_trex" class="button style2 down anchored" title="DINOSUARS TREX">down</a>

    </section>
    <section id="dinosaurs_trex" class="main style2 left dark fullscreen">
        <div class="content box style2">
            <header>
                 <h2>TREX</h2>

            </header>
            <p>Section for the Trex</p>
        </div> <a href="#dinosaurs" class="button style2 up anchored" title="page1">up</a>
     <a href="#dinosaurs_raptor" class="button style2 down anchored" title="page3">down</a>

    </section>
    <section id="dinosaurs_raptor" class="main style2 left dark fullscreen">
        <div class="content box style2">
            <header>
                 <h2>THE RAPTOR</h2>

            </header>
            <p>Section for the Trex</p>
        </div> <a href="#dinosaurs_trex" class="button style2 up anchored"       title="page1">up</a>
     <a href="#robots" class="button style2 down anchored" title="page3">down</a>

    </section>
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4qwawrgx/

Comment: I have added my HTML so theres a better explanation of my setup.

Comment: Ah, thanks for making the fiddle; I guess I need to explain my unique needs better, basically I want all the dinosaur sections to only highlight one dinosaur nav item as the user is scrolling thru the dinos. Then I want the robot sections to only highlight the one robot nav item, in your current fiddle you've assigned the different dinos to the different nav items. let me know if you need more info. thanks

Comment: Im not following. The nav you gave had "Dinos, Robots, Undead" as options. If you just want dinos to highlight when they are in that section change waypoints to target "#dinosaurs" and just grab the link for dinos and add active

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean I want the dino section to have an intro section, that highlights the dinos nav bar, but then I want another section for dinos - trex as its own section, but i want it to still highlight the 'one' dino nav link - then as the user scrolls down past the dino intro and trex intro section i want the dinos - raptor 'section' to still also highlight the one 'dinos' nav item .. does that. help out?

Comment: so basically i want all three dino related sections: <section id="dinosaurs"> <section id="dinosaurs_trex"> <section id="dinosaurs_raptor"> to only have one active 'dinos' nav item active when scrolling through them..

Comment: I also did some more digging.. im convinced I can somehow include some word variable like this snippet $("#left ul li a:contains('" + dinosaurs + "')").addClass('active'); into my version of nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');  I just dont know how to reformat my code snippet to include the a:contains(' "blah "') stuff... If someone can help out .. so what did does I think is group all sections that have 'dinosaur' in it, to a single activated nav link

Answer (score 0):

change your this code

```
nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
```

to this

```
function activateNav() {
    var hashValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    $('body').find('a[href="#'+ hashValue +'"]').addClass('active');
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    activateNav();
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        activateNav();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for that, but unfortunately that did not work. Just to recap I have a nav item called `<li><a href="#dinos_" title="ALL DINOS">ALL DINOS</a></li>` and I want three separate section ids that are <section id="dinos_"> <section id="dinos_trex"><section id="dinos_raptor"> to all highlight the one nav item #dinos_ ..